# Mismatch between CMD and selenium run

Tags: selenium, maven, cmd, selenium-chromedriver, testng

I am trying to run some classes via CMD with the command : mvn test

When I run it throw the eclipse with testng it's run well.

But when I am trying to run it from CMD I got this message :

```
session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 97
Current browser version is 99.0.4844.51
```

My chromedriver is :

```
C:\Program Files\Selenium\ChromeDriver>chromeDriver -v
ChromeDriver 99.0.4844.51
```

What is the problem ?
From where its take the sentence "This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 97" ?
How can I make it works please ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download ChromeDriver v99

Which you can find [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=99.0.4844.51/)

Comment: 0


As I mentioned in the question, I downloaded the correct chromedriver and even added a snippet of code from CMD that shows that what is installed is version 99

Answer (score 0):

There can be a different version of the chrome driver (in your case version 97) present in the path or in the same folder.
Alternatively, you can pass the full path of chromedriver.exe when you are initializing the driver.

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\Selenium\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')`

Comment: This is my initializing, how can I write it ? 
   'System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Program Files\\Selenium\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");

        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

        options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/meironb/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data");
        options.addArguments("--start-maximized");

        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);'